# an html element can have more then one CSS class setted?

Tags: html, css

an HTML element can have more than a CSS class?

If it is possible how can I set 2 classes on a h1?

For example I am trying to set 2 classes (text-center and title) on this element but in this way can't work:

```
<h1 class="text-center, title"><small>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h1>
```

Tnx

Comment: Just a comment... remember to close that `<small>` tag.

Comment: http://flukeout.github.io/# this site is good for you if you want to learn about how to use css with html.

Comment: remove the comma, just use space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a space, eg:

`<h1 class="text-center title"><small>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h1>`

Comment: Follow up comment - I hope you're closing that `small` tag before the `h1` closing tag!

Answer (score 1):

An HTML element can have any number of classes. In a [`class` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-class), the class names are separated by spaces or, generally, by sequences of whitespace characters. This is not a CSS issue at all. There are no “CSS classes”; CSS has just class selectors (which refer to elements by their classes as set in HTML).

Example:

```
<h1 class="text-center title">
```

However, in this case, the class names suggest that you should design the coding differently. Class names work best when they reflect intended structual or semantic role rather than specific rendering details. It is quite possible that you could use just one class here, or no classes: a page normally has just one `h1` element, so you can style it using the `h1` selector.